# Where's the official manifest.json documentation for Chrome Hosted Apps? (bookmark/shortcut apps)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chromium, google-chrome-os

The simplest Google Chrome apps seem to be those that just act as a bookmark or shortcut to a Web site. They have a `manifest.json` that is something like this:

```
{  
  "manifest_version": 2,  
  "version": "0.1",  
  "short_name": "stackoverflow",  
  "name": "stackoverflow shortcut",  
  "description": "stackoverflow bookmark chrome app",  
  "icons": { "128": "img/128.png" },  
  "minimum_chrome_version":"37.0.0.0",  
  "app": {  
    "urls": [ "http://stackoverflow.com/" ],  
    "launch": { "web_url": "http://stackoverflow.com/" }  
  },  
}
```

The basics of this are documented in the [Getting Started Tutorial Sample](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple) and in the [Create a private Chrome app page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en) this type of app appears to be referred to there as a **bookmark app**.

My questions are:

- Is **bookmark app** is an *official* term for this kind of Chrome app? As I am having difficulty finding any other official place it is referred to in such a way
- Where is `manifest.json` fully documented? The [extension manifest.json documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) does not even contain info for the `app` name tag, and the [main manifest.json doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) doesn't mention the `urls`, `launch`, and `web_url` elements?

The tags are fairly self explanatory and used in many tutorials all over the Web but it seems odd there is no official documentation for them, especially when `app` is used for more complex Chrome apps - I just want to make sure I am not somehow missing some official and more complete documentation as I am referring to this type of app wrongly.

Maybe it is simply that *the code is the documentation* and I simply need to find where the `manifest.json` is parsed in the [Chromium code](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code). I thought it was worth asking here first though, and even if I end up being told to check the code then someone might give me a pointer there to get me started.

Comment: Not an answer but here's something: 1. [developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) describes the `app` key but not the parameters. 2. Apparently there's just one doc page about `launch`, `web_url` and `urls`: [getting started](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple#step2). 3 To quickly lookup something in the source code use [chromium code search](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=manifest%20web_url%20lang:%5Ec%2B%2B$%20case:yes&sq=package:chromium&type=cs).

Comment: Thanks for the better manifest.json doc link @wOxxOm it would be nice if the [app keyword](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/app) link took us to fuller docs but I guess this is not currently the case. I'll update the Q with your info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bookmark" apps you describe are officially called *hosted apps*. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/overview#concepts) you have a description of both:

> Apps
>
> Contains **installable web apps**. An installable web app can be a normal website with a bit of extra metadata; this type of app is called a **hosted app**. Alternatively, an installable web app can bundle all its content into an archive that users download when they install the app; this is a **packaged app**. Both hosted and packaged apps have icons in Chrome's New Tab page, and most users shouldn't be able to tell the difference between them without looking at the address bar.

The [documentation for app manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) only describes the options for packaged apps. As @wOxxOm notes in the comments, the only place currently describing a manifest for a hosted app seems to be the [Getting Started](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple#step2) tutorial.

Comment: I had repeatedly come across the term **hosted app** AND read the documentation you link to above quite a few times and yet still had not connected the term with these minimalist apps - doh! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and clarifying. Once I searched using this terminology it does bring up a few more relevant articles but as you say the current state of play seems to be the only real documentation of them is the tutorial. Maybe this can be updated if more explicit documentation ever is created.

Comment: bookmark apps are discouraged and may be rejected by the store (even thou google has a bunch of them that simply open a url and do nothing else like their sheets and docs apps)

Comment: @ZigMandel could you give any references that provide evidence of this _discouragement_? It is true that there are restrictions on public hosted apps in the CWS only being links to sites the publisher is a verified owner of, and they are not exactly well documented by Google; but I have not see any docs from Google to suggest there status is anything other than the simplest form of a Chrome App.

Comment: I remember reading about it but dont recall where. i was hoping that someone here would also clarify.